dynamic row discarded from an HTML form why?
I have an HTML page in which I add some form row interactively via JS, the php code that I wrote to save the content of this row and of other field on different table on db save only the first row while discard all other row added dynamically, the form action is post and the enctype is multipart/form-data.
This is the part of the page that add the row:
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Create Estimate</h2>

        <?php if (isset($message)): ?>
            <div class="message"><?php echo $message; ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="formintestazione">
            <form method="POST" action="create_estimate.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="section">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="location">Location:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="location" name="location" value="Sciacca" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="date">Date:</label>
                        <input type="date" id="date" name="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="estimate_type">Estimate Type:</label>
                        <select id="estimate_type" name="estimate_type" onchange="updateEstimateNumber()" required>
                            <option value="">Select Estimate Type</option>
                            <option value="OFF_n">OFF_n</option>
                            <option value="OFF_B2B">OFF_B2B</option>
                            <option value="OFF_EGov_n">OFF_EGov_n</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="estimate_number">Estimate Number:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="estimate_number" name="estimate_number" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="recipient_id">Recipient:</label>
                        <select id="recipient_id" name="recipient_id" onchange="updateRecipientDetails()" required>
                            <option value="">Select Recipient</option>
                            <?php foreach ($recipients as $recipient): ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $recipient['id']; ?>"
                                        data-details="<?php echo $recipient['address'] . ', ' . $recipient['zip_code'] . ' - ' . $recipient['city'] . ' - ' . $recipient['province']; ?>">
                                    <?php echo $recipient['company_name']; ?>
                                </option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <p id="recipientDetails"></p> <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="editor">Editor:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="editor" name="editor" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
                        <textarea id="subject" name="subject" maxlength="255" rows="3" required></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <input type="hidden" id="draft" name="draft" value="YES">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <h2>Add Estimate Items</h2>

                <div id="items-container">
                    <div class="item" data-item-number="1">
                        <h3>Item 1</h3>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label for="item_number_1">Item Number:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="item_number_1" name="item_number[]" value="1" readonly>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label for="item_type_1">Item Type:</label>
                            <select id="item_type_1" name="item_type[]" onchange="handlePrice(1)">
                                <option value="paragraph">Paragraph</option>
                                <option value="description">Description</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label for="image_1">Image:</label>
                            <input type="file" id="image_1" name="image[]">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label for="description_1">Description:</label>
                            <textarea id="description_1" name="description[]" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label for="price_1">Price (€):</label>
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" id="price_1" name="price[]">
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="remove-row-btn" onclick="removeItem(this)">Remove Item</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button type="button" class="add-row-btn" onclick="addItem()">Add Item</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <button type="submit" name="save" value="Save" class="add-row-btn">Save Estimate</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        let itemNumber = 1;

        // Function to add a new item
        function addItem() {
            itemNumber++;
            const itemsContainer = document.getElementById('items-container');

            const newItem = document.createElement('div');
            newItem.classList.add('item');   

            newItem.setAttribute('data-item-number', itemNumber);

            newItem.innerHTML = `
                <h3>Item ${itemNumber}</h3>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="item_number_${itemNumber}">Item Number:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="item_number_${itemNumber}" name="item_number[]" value="${itemNumber}" readonly>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="item_type_${itemNumber}">Item Type:</label>
                    <select id="item_type_${itemNumber}" name="item_type[]" onchange="handlePrice(${itemNumber})">
                        <option value="paragraph">Paragraph</option>
                        <option value="description">Description</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="image_${itemNumber}">Image:</label>
                    <input type="file" id="image_${itemNumber}" name="image[]">
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="description_${itemNumber}">Description:</label>
                    <textarea id="description_${itemNumber}" name="description[]" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="price_${itemNumber}">Price (€):</label>
                    <input type="number" step="0.01" id="price_${itemNumber}" name="price[]">
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="remove-row-btn" onclick="removeItem(this)">Remove Item</button>
            `;

            itemsContainer.appendChild(newItem);
        }

        // Function to remove an item
        function removeItem(button) {
            const item = button.closest('.item');
            item.remove();
        }

        // Function to handle the price field based on the item type
        function handlePrice(itemNumber) {
            const itemType = document.getElementById(`item_type_${itemNumber}`).value;
            const priceField = document.getElementById(`price_${itemNumber}`);

            if (itemType === 'paragraph') {
                priceField.disabled = true;
                priceField.value = ''; // Reset the price field if disabled
            } else {
                priceField.disabled = false;
            }
        }

        // Initialization of the first item
        document.getElementById('item_type_1').addEventListener('change', function() {
            handlePrice(1);
        });
    </script>
</body>

 

While the php code that save the content is the following, it seems that it discard all the row added successively via js and doesn't store the same, why the row were discarded i have developed another example in which all seems functioning correctly and even no row were discarded
<?php
// Enable error reporting for development purposes (remove in production)
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Database connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username   
 = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tli_estimates"; // Replace with your database name

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);   

}

// Retrieve a list of recipients from the Customers table with all details
$sql = "SELECT id, company_name, address, zip_code, city, province FROM Customers";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$recipients = [];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $recipients[] = $row;
    }
}

// Handle form submission
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get form data
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $estimate_type = $_POST['estimate_type'];
    $estimate_number = $_POST['estimate_number'];
    $recipient_id = $_POST['recipient_id'];
    $editor = $_POST['editor'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $draft = $_POST['draft'];

    // Insert the estimate into the Estimates table
    $sqlEstimate = "INSERT INTO Estimates (estimate_number, estimate_type, recipient_id, location, date, editor, subject, draft)
                  VALUES ('$estimate_number', '$estimate_type', '$recipient_id', '$location', '$data', '$editor', '$subject', '$draft')";

    if ($conn->query($sqlEstimate) === TRUE) {
        $message = ($draft == 'SI') ? "Estimate saved as draft!" : "Estimate saved successfully!";
    } else {
        $message = "Error during insertion: " . $conn->error;
    }

    // Handle estimate items
    // Get the estimate number
    $estimate_number = isset($_POST['estimate_number']) ? $_POST['estimate_number'] : null;

    // If the estimate number is empty, stop here
    if (empty($estimate_number)) {
        die("Error: Missing estimate number.");
    }

    // Loop through all submitted items
    if (isset($_POST['item_number']) && is_array($_POST['item_number'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['item_number'] as $index => $item_number) {
            // Get data from the current item
            $item_type = $_POST['item_type'][$index];
            $description = $_POST['description'][$index];
            $price = ($_POST['price'][$index] != "") ? $_POST['price'][$index] : 0.00; // If empty, set to 0.00

            // Handle image upload as a BLOB
            $image = null;
            if (isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$index]) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$index])) {
                $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$index]));
            }

            // Insert the item into the database
            $sqlItem = "INSERT INTO EstimateItems (estimate_number, item_number, item_type, image, description, price)
                       VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            // Prepare the SQL statement
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlItem);
            if (!$stmt) {
                die("Error preparing statement: " . $conn->error);
            }

            // Bind parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("sisssd", $estimate_number, $item_number, $item_type, $image, $description, $price);

            // Execute the query
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                echo "Item $item_number inserted successfully!<br>";
            } else {
                echo "Error inserting item $item_number: " . $stmt->error . "<br>";
            }

            // Close the statement
            $stmt->close();
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error: No items found.";
    }
}
$conn->close();

 


it seems that...ok, so what debugging have you done, to narrow down exactly what the issue is. Does the Network tool in the browser tell you that the form data was submitted to the server successfully? What does PHP tell you is within $_POST when you dump it out? What does your debugging tell you about where in the PHP code the execution reached, and how many times it looped etc? Is there a specific reason you haven't done any such investigations before posting this? (Or if you did, why didn't you think it was useful to mention what you found out?). Please narrow down the specific issue

I have debugged with a dump print_r of the post variable and it shows only one set of field variable even if i added more than one row dinamically, in another example without the header field of the estimate number and the estimate type the row were saved correctly

Your HTML nesting has problems. <div id="items-container"> is not nested inside <form>

Use an IDE which shows you HTML tag structure and validation. You have an extra </div> which is messing up the nesting. Even just in JSFiddle it will highlight the mistake for you immediately: https://jsfiddle.net/kmt5ejxa/

Yes it's true i verified the problem was in HTML nesting
